# SignalR Not Invoking Server Method

Tags: c#, async-await, signalr

I am having an issue trying to invoke a method on a SignalR server when trying to fire and forget.

I currently call the method as follows:

```
isSuccessful = await _myHub.Invoke<bool>("SendNotification", notification).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This works fine but when creating a lot of notifications it can slow down my application. After consideration, I don't need the boolean being returned and therefore don't need to await the call.

I changed the invoke to now look like this:

```
_myHub.Invoke("SendNotification", notification);
```

While the first one seemed to always work, this one no longer hits the server and never sends the notification as it should. I'm unsure why if I return and await the value that it works but that it doesn't if I don't need anything back.

If I do need the await, how do I speed the call up when sending thousands of notification objects over the socket?

Comment: Does the other side still return a bool? It may not be happy about you ignoring the return value

Comment: I changed it to return void on the hub side. Still no dice.

Comment: Odd. You could also try awaiting the task returned by `Invoke` to make sure it runs.